# VBscript compiler

Tags: vbscript, compiler-construction

Can anyone recommend a free VBScript compiler?

Comment: I have a trial copy of this:
http://www.abyssmedia.com/scriptcryptor/index.shtml
but was hoping for a free one.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Not exactly an executable but you can create an HTA (HTML Application) which can be run in a browser. Take a look at this very simple tutorial at MSDN: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx

Comment: A good free VBS-to-EXE compiler is HTWOO by Hadi Kiamarsi. It is listed as a tool for "Python script to EXE" but then you find out that it also does VBS to EXE and many more compilations/EXE wrappings for free. Screenshot: http://img507.imageshack.us/img507/263/l0s.gif
Download: https://sourceforge.net/projects/htwoo/
Youtube tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWOFt0SYyEo

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425681/how-can-i-convert-a-vbscript-to-an-executable-exe-file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0aew7h6.aspx) is an interpreted language, not a compiled one. If you want to make a binary executable out of your VBScript code, you will need to port it to Visual Basic or Visual Basic .NET first. As for free compilers, [Visual Basic .NET Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vb/default.aspx) edition is available for free.

Comment: There isn't really any such thing as an interpreted *language* - a language is a language, whether or not it is interpreted or compiled is all down to whether or not we put it through an interpreter or a compiler.  Perhaps the convention is that we normally interpret some languages and compile others, but there is no real reason why VBScript can't be parsed and compiled instead of interpreted.

Answer (score 12):

You can do it for free with [Vbsedit](http://www.vbsedit.com)

Comment: It's true. How come this answer has no upvotes? This is the simplest way to create an executable. You just need your VBScript code.

Comment: Although you can "evaluate" Vbsedit for "free" - every EXE you make will have a nag message.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to compile VBScript in order to hide something like a password, you're probably doing it wrong.

This compiler is $49: http://www.xuebrothers.net/sh/sh.htm and has a free demo.

Any compiler for this language promptly turns it back into the plaintext script before running it, so you lose the benefit of obscurity against any determined attacker. If you absolutely won't pay for any of the compilers, your best bet might be to re-write it using one of the free visual studio basic variants, and compile that.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/

Answer (score 0):

Yes... you can definitely use VbsEdit.. download evaluation copy from http://www.vbsedit.com/

OR

save the file as .vbs file and try to execute the same with double clicking the file... debugging is little tough job...

Answer (score 0):

Could use Mono. It's free. Also available for Linux, Mac, as well as PC.