# How to make a lib file from a VBScript?

Tags: windows, vbscript

I have a VBScript file, in which my functions are defined. In my other VBScripts i include this file, and so i can use the defined functions. My Problem is, that this way, anyone can see my predefined functions. Is it possible somehow to make a lib or some other file from my VBScript file, which i can include in my later VBScripts, and use it's functions?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBscript compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434079/vbscript-compiler)

Answer (score 2):

VBScript doesn't have an import concept, so what you want isn't really supported in plain VBScript. There is a [workaround](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/importvbs.shtml), though, utilizing the [`ExecuteGlobal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/342311f1%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) statement:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
code = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\library.vbs").ReadAll
ExecuteGlobal code
```

You can also import other script files in WSF scripts (see [this sample chapter](http://oreilly.com/catalog/vbscriptian/chapter/ch02.html) from *VBScript in a Nutshell*, section "Reusable Code Libraries"):

```
<PACKAGE>
<JOB ID=Sample>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript" SRC="C:\path\to\library.vbs" />
<SCRIPT>
result = FunctionFromLibrary("arg1", "arg2")
</SCRIPT>
</JOB>
</PACKAGE>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Window Script Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07zhfkh8%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

This basically allows you to wrap up your VBScript code as a COM object, making it accessible via `CreateObject()`.

Your code is still stored in plain text, however.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, but the reason why i want to make a lib is that, that my code should not be in plain text :)